# The procedure entry point EVP_md2 could not be located in the dynalic link library

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

When i try to run `cURL` in command-line i got message

`the procedure entry point EVP_md2 could not be located in the dynalic link library D:\wamp\www\apps\curl\libssl32.dll.`
any help with any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found some usefull information on this page http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2007-03/0075.html. It seems that you need to adjust your Path sequence. There might be other libssl32.dll.